# How can I fix these php warnings errors?

Tags: php

I use Dragonbytetech addons on my vBulletin forum and I am having an issue when installing some of them.

According to my web hosting, here are the php warnings :

[17-Aug-2021 09:32:02 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): (42000/1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' 0),(1, 2, , 0),(1, 3, , 0),(1, 4, , 0),(1, 5, , 0),(1, 6, , 0),(1, 7, , 0),(...' at line 4 in /home/edengene/public_html/forum/includes/class_core.php on line 1386

[17-Aug-2021 09:47:29 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): (42S22/1054): Unknown column 'displayorder' in 'field list' in /home/edengene/public_html/forum/includes/class_core.php on line 1386

DragonByteTech don't seem to be able to help me on this so I have to find a solution all by myself, with the help of competent individuals like you.

Thank you in advance for your invaluable help!

Answer (score 0):

Error 1:
The error is exactly what it says, you have an error in your SQL syntax and because of it you get the error and your query probably doesn't work.

Error 2:
Almost the same, you are in this case asking for a column that is not in your database.

Now I don't know Dragonbytetech, but if you are not programming this yourself and you do not have any issues you could just turn it off and get the next update which will hopefully fix it. It is an issue with the SQL query in the programming in both cases.